# Closure for simple use case

Tags: python, closures

I do not understand the following practice interview question:

> `cons(a, b)` constructs a pair, and `car(pair)` and `cdr(pair)` return the
>   first and last element of that pair. For example, `car(cons(3, 4))`
>   returns `3`, and `cdr(cons(3, 4))` returns `4`.
>
> Given this implementation of cons:
>
> ```
> def cons(a, b):
>     def pair(f):
>         return f(a, b)
>     return pair
> ```
>
> Implement car and cdr.

What is the practical application of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cons is a function that takes 2 arguments and return a funtion that applies a function into a pair, so we can build up `car` and `cdr` in the same fasion:

```
def car(pair):
    def unpack(a, b):
        return a
    return pair(unpack)


def cdr(pair):
    def unpack(a, b):
        return b
    return pair(unpack)
```

This is an example/exercise that comes from functional programing, in where everything can be abstracted to functions (talking simply).
It has real usage in with languages as `Haskell` or `Racket` for example. But I don't think it should be a real production ready option for python (IMO).

As you can see, there are no variables involved in the code others but the arguments themselves:

```
>>> car(cons(1, 2))
1
>>> cdr(cons(1, 2))
2
```

Comment: I think you meant to say "**`cons`** is a function that takes 2 arguments ..."